# how to get each html select id value in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i want to get each id value of select by using jquery. each id has unique value as i am generating select in `php` loop and placing unique product id in id.

following is my code:

```
<select id="<?=$item['id']?>" class="prodsize" name="size" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    <option value="" id="0">Choose Your Size</option>
        <?php

          $prodid = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name = '".$item['name']."'")->row()->id;

          $sizequery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM size WHERE product_id = " . $prodid . " and status = 1");
            if($sizequery->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach($sizequery->result() as $row) 
                {
                    $prodsize = $row->size_from .' x '. $row->size_to;
                ?>
    <option value="<?=$prodsize?>" id="<?=$row->price?>">
                <?=$row->size_from?>
                  x
                  <?=$row->size_to?>
                  </option>
         <?php } } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: could you share you html output? so we don't have to rewrite the markup.. also a http://jsfiddle.net would be nice and maybe you show what you have tried in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do something with all selects in a loop you can do

```
$("select").each(function(){
   var cur_id = $(this).attr("id");
   // do stuff with cur_id
});
```

If you wanna get select's id inside an event like changing a select value then

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
   var cur_id = $(this).attr("id");
   // do stuff with cur_id
});
```